# Mostrar todos los registros de un campo de MySQL en un Select HTML

Tags: html, sql, select

Buenas noches, estoy realizando un sistema para la universidad de la reservación de unos miniauditorios, Un (01) usuario puede realizar varias reservaciones y luego de reservarlas el usuario debe informar el pago a través de la subida de un pdf.

Al usuario le muestro un formulario para informar el pago subiendo el pdf con el numero de la reservación y el miniauditorio, pero si tengo varias reservaciones necesito mostrarselas todas para que el seleccione cual de todas las reservaciones que hizo pagó y desea informar, como tengo el codigo ahora solo me muestra la primera reservación y deseo que cuando le de un click al "select" HTML me despliegue todas los numeros de reservaciones que tiene junto con el miniauditorio asociado a dicha reservación. A continuación les dejo el codigo(les pido disculpas, estoy aprendiendo y seguramente tengo muchos errores):

```html
<?php
session_start();
 include '/login/funcs/funcs.php';
 include_once 'config.inc.php';
 
 if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
  header("Location: index.php");
 }
 
 $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
 
 
  
  $db=new Conect_MySql();
  $sql2 = "SELECT `idsolicitudes`, `id`, `nombre_sala` FROM solicitudes WHERE `id`=$idUsuario";
  $query2 = $db->execute($sql2);
  $datos=$db->fetch_row($query2);
  
  $sql3 = "SELECT `id`, `usuario`, `nombre`, `apellido` FROM usuarios WHERE `id`=$idUsuario";
  $query3 = $db->execute($sql3);
  $datos2=$db->fetch_row($query3);
  
   echo $datos['usuario'];
?>
 
 



<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->



<html>
  
  <?php


if (isset($_POST['subir'])) {
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "archivos/" . $nombre;
    if ($nombre != "") {
        if (copy($ruta, $destino)) {
            $titulo= $_POST['titulo'];
            $descri= $_POST['descripcion'];
   $solicitud = $_POST ['solicitud'];
            $db=new Conect_MySql();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_documentos(idsolicitud, id, titulo,descripcion,tamanio,tipo,nombre_archivo) VALUES('$solicitud','$idUsuario','$titulo','$descri','$tamanio','$tipo','$nombre')";
            $query = $db->execute($sql);
            if($query){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("Buen trabajo!","Hemos recibido la información de tu pago, pero primero debemos confirmarla, espera por nuestro correo electrónico con información detallada!","success");';
    echo '}, 1000);</script>';
    
   /*
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">swal(\"Se guardó correctamente\");
    window.location.href='/login/welcome.php';
    </script>";*/
    
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
}
?>
  
<body>
  <div align="center" class="main"> <!-- Primer Div Parallax --> 
  <div class="container" id="stuff">
        <div style="width: 500px; margin: auto; style=background-color:white; padding: 30px;">
            <h2 id="stuff" style="background-color:#1c1c1c"><b>Informános tu pago</b></h2>
    <h4 ><b>Sube tu comprobante de deposito o transferencia solo despues de haber <a href="/login/reservar.php">reservado</a></b></h4>
            
   
   <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table>
    
     <div class="form-group">
                    <tr>
     
                        <td><label>Miniauditorio</label></td>
       
                        <td><div class="col-sm-10">
        <select id="disabledSelect" name="titulo"  style="WIDTH: 228px; HEIGHT: 40px"  class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $datos['nombre_sala']; ?>">
       <option placeholder="<?php echo $datos['idsolicitud']; ?>"><?php echo $datos['nombre_sala']; ?></option>
       
        </select>
       </div>
      </td>
      </div>
                    </tr>
     </div>
                    <tr> 
                        <td><label><br />Nombre Titular</label></td>
                        <td><br /><input style="WIDTH: 250px; HEIGHT: 35px"  class="form-control" style="color:black" name="descripcion" disabled value="<?php echo $datos2['nombre']; ?> <?php echo $datos2['apellido']; ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
     <img class="img2" src="/login/images/pdficon.png">
     <tr> 
                        <td><label><br />Número de Solicitud</label></td>
                        <td><div class="col-sm-10">
        <select id="disabledSelect" name="titulo"  style="WIDTH: 228px; HEIGHT: 40px"  class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $datos['nombre_sala']; ?>">
       <option placeholder="<?php echo $datos['idsolicitud']; ?>"><?php echo $datos['idsolicitudes']; ?></option>
       
        </select>
                    </tr>
               
                        <td colspan="2"><br />
      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
      <input type="file" name="archivo"></td>
      </span>
      <div align="center">
      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="center"><br /><input align="center" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Subir" name="subir"></td>
                       <!-- <td><a href="lista.php">lista</a></td> -->
      
                    </tr>
     </div>
     
                </table>
    
    <h4><b>Antes de enviarnos su información, verifique que su archivo este guardado en formato PDF</b></h2>
            </form>            
        </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Posible imagen<img src="https://i.imgur.com/5utiwXU.jpg">-->
  
  
    </body>
</html>
```

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas, Agrego el codigo de conexión.

```html
<?php 

class Conect_MySql {   
     var $obj = array ( "dbname" => "login",
                       "dbuser"  => "root"  ,
                       "dbpwd"  => ""  ,
                       "dbhost"  => "localhost" );


     var $q_id ="";
     var $ExeBit ="";
     var $db_connect_id = "";
     var $query_count   = 0;
    private function connect(){
  $this->db_connect_id = mysqli_connect($this->obj['dbhost'],$this->obj['dbuser'],$this->obj['dbpwd'],$this->obj['dbname']);
             if (!$this->db_connect_id)
              {
                echo (" Error no se puede conectar al servidor:".mysqli_connect_error());
       }
  }

function execute($query) {       
        $this->q_id = mysqli_query($this->db_connect_id,$query);        
        if(!$this->q_id ) {
            $error1 = mysqli_error($this->db_connect_id);
            die ("ERROR: error DB.<br> No Se Puede Ejecutar La Consulta:<br> $query <br>MySql Tipo De Error: $error1");
            exit;
        }         
 $this->query_count++; 
 return $this->q_id;    
    }


  public function fetch_row($q_id = "") {
     if ($q_id == "") {
      $q_id = $this->q_id;
      }
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($q_id);
        return $result;
    } 

 public function get_num_rows() {
        return mysqli_num_rows($this->q_id);
    }

public function get_row_affected(){
    return mysqli_affected_rows($this->db_connect_id);
}

public function get_insert_id() {
    return mysqli_insert_id($this->db_connect_id);
}

public  function free_result($q_id) {
     if($q_id == ""){
      $q_id = $this->q_id;
  }
 mysqli_free_result($q_id);
    } 

public function close_db(){
        return mysqli_close($this->db_connect_id);
    }

public function more_result() {
  return mysqli_more_results($this->db_connect_id);
 }
public function next_result() {
  return mysqli_next_result($this->db_connect_id);
 }

  public function __construct(){
        $this->connect();
    }
  
}
?>
```

Comment: Tienes dos opciones: **1.** Almacenar todos tus resultados en una variable y luego recorrer esta variable dentro de un bucle para ir construyendo las `option`  de tu `select`. Esta opción no es recomendable si esperas una gran cantidad de resultados. **2.** Abrir un puntero de tus resultados e irlos recorriendo dentro de un bucle `while`...  Sería dentro de ese bucle que construirías las `option` de tu `select`. Es la opción habitual, sobre todo cuando se esperan muchos datos. Como veo que usas tu propia clase de conexión, no podría ponerte ejemplos. Tu clase conexión podría tener esos métodos

Comment: Muchas gracias A. Cedano, no tienes ni idea de cuanto me has ayudado, pero me hablaste en chino jejeje

Comment: [Mira aquí un ejemplo de lo que te digo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/i6by-yq8q)... sólo que este ejemplo está con PDO, pero el principio es el mismo:  **Tener un arreglo con los resultados y recorrerlo construyendo tus elementos, o recorrer los resultados dentro de un puntero y construir los elementos**. En este ejemplo se construye una tabla a partir de los resultados. Lo tuyo sería lo mismo, pero con un `select` en vez de una tabla. La parte interesante es a partir de aquí: `foreach ($arrDatos as $row)...` Veré si tengo un ejemplo con `mysqli`, no sé lo que estás usando si PDO o mysqli.

Comment: Acabo de agregar el codigo de conexión.

Comment: **[Aquí hay un ejemplo usando `MySQLi`](https://gist.github.com/phpfiddle/da1635d3967beba0a3c616db16837b57)**, el cual aplica además una norma de seguridad muy importante: usa consultas preparadas para evitar la inyección SQL. El código, igual que el anterior, construye una tabla a partir de los resultados y usa un método llamado `get_result` que no existe en todas las extensiones de mysqli y que facilita este tipo de cosas. Si procedes así, cambiando la tabla por cualquier otro elemento valdría. Puse explicaciones amplias en el código, para que pudiera servir como orientación en estos casos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, revisaré el codigo y veré si lo puedo adaptar a mi sistema, muchas gracias! :)